# I don't see where i am supposed to at the ':'

Tags: python-2.7

```
a = raw_input("What do you want to add to the list?"
              " If you would like to remove something from the list type 'remove' : ")
if str(a) not == "remove".lower():
    print('"'), str(a), ('"' " has been added to list")
    list1.append(a)
    print(list1)
```

When i run this (there is more code but this is the relevant bit) it says "expected ':'" just before the not in the "if str(a) not == "remove".lower():" line. keep in mind that this is on python 2.7

Comment: Syntax is wrong.  Use `!=` not `not ==`.  This is covered in basic tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

To test for inequality in Python this is valid:

```
A != B
```

and so is this:

```
not (A == B)
```

but this is not:

```
A not == B    # syntax error
```

(You could be forgiven for thinking that's how it works if you've been using the `in` operator,  because `not (A in B)` and `A not in B` *are* equivalent.)

Once you have fixed that, know that this:

```
print('"'), str(a), ('"' " has been added to list")
```

is cursed, and only accidentally does what you want in Python 2 (it won't do what you evidently assume it does in any currently-supported Python version).  When you want to `print()` something, the specification of what is to be printed ends at that first `)`.  The following works in both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
print( '"{}" has been added to list'.format(a) )
```

Then there's the fact that you are applying `.lower()` to the wrong side of a comparison (to something that is already always lower-case).

Comment: I'm assuming i would make it print(('"'), str(a), ('"' " has been added to list")) (i thought i had that before but oh well. also thanks!

Comment: @N018B I spoke too soon.  What you wrote *will* actually work in Python 2.x but its syntax is very misleading. Answer updated.